# Plugin for average distance from node to polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, analysis

Is there a plugin available that will calculate this?

EDIT 1:

The red polyline is the average distance of the point to the black polyline. The red polyline is what I want to display. Alternatively, is there something which would calculate the radius of the circle so I can use a buffer?

[image]

Comment: Could you illustrate what you mean by "average" distance?

Comment: @underdark; EDIT 1 added with image

Comment: Are your polylines always boundaries of polygons that contain the point in question?

Comment: @underdark It doesn't matter whether the polygon is closed or not, nor does it matter where the "node" is located.

Comment: @underdark The polygons have been created using the Voronoi polygons tools, and the point is one of the nodes. So in this case the node is always within the polygon/polyline.

Comment: @Robert I'm curious what you plan to use this average distance for.  The reason is that there are other possible valid interpretations of "average distance" between a node and the boundary of its Voronoi cell.  For instance, one might ask of any point in a forest, "how far should I expect to go in order to leave the woods if I head off in a random direction and continue straight?"  The answers given here do *not* address that question!

Comment: @whuber The application is as follows: The nodes represent retail locations, the polygons represent a Voronoi cell which is a store's catchment area (or households closest to the store). A shopper's propensity to visit the store reduces with distance form the store. By calculating the average distance to the boundary one can discount the potential catchment area income in proportion to the distance a shopper would travel.

Comment: @Robert It sounds like you want the mean distance *for all points within the polygon,* not along the boundary.  (This is the sense in which I originally answered the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using QGIS and GRASS, this should be doable:

1. Split the line using [v.segment](https://web.archive.org/web/20110828073204/http://grass.osgeo.org:80/grass62/manuals/html62_user/v.segment.html)
2. Add the point you want to calculate avg distance for
3. Use QGIS "Distance Matrix"
4. The last column in the matrix should contain all distances. You just need to calculate the mean.

I'm sure there is a GRASS alternative to distance matrix ([v.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.distance.html)?). As far as I know, there is no equivalent to v.segment in QGIS yet.

Comment: +1 Thank you for translating this into a QGIS workflow.  It's a pity you need other software for the splitting into points, though.  In fact, in addition to GRASS you also need some script or software to generate the distance offsets along the polyline, as far as I can tell.  But the workflow should succeed.

Comment: v.segment is now available though QGIS Processing.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely QGIS (or any software) has implemented the exact formulas provided in the [antecedent thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/transform-polygon-to-equivalent-circle-qgis), but one could sample a polyline at regular intervals, compute the distances between the sample points and the "node," and average them: these are common operations available in many GISes.  (This is a [Riemann Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), or rectangular, approximation to the integral. Improved approximations, such as with the [Trapezoidal Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule), can be implemented similarly.  Correct application of Simpson's Rule would require estimating the average distances separately over each segment of the polyline and then forming the segment-length-weighted average of those results.)

### Example

[image: AV 3 screenshot]

This screenshot (using ArcView 3, an old simple GIS :-) illustrates the procedure.  A 10 km feature in a road layer (barely visible in black) has been sampled at 100 m intervals  (shown in darker cyan) beginning at a random location.  Another point layer containing a single point (shown as a cross) has been *spatially joined* to the sample points.  One result of the join is to compute a [distance] value to each of the sample points, shown in the table at left.  A statistics dialog displays the mean distance (of 3503 meters), shown highlighted.  A circle of that radius (red) was manually added based on that information.